# Why does my animation for moving left and right not work?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite-sheet

I'm working on making my character have a walking animation, but for some reason the left and right animation isn't working even though my up and down walking animation is. Whenever I move left or right, it flips my character as if he were walking up, yet it doesn't play the up animation either. I've looked over the code a million times, but I don't see any differences between the way I have the up and down animations compared to the left and right set up, so I just don't know what could be wrong. Below I have the player class code written out, as I'm 99% sure that the problem lies therein. I will also record a gif of the problem as it plays out in the game, as well as put a pastebin of the whole code, just in case the Player class isn't enough. https://pastebin.com/968pjEmc https://gyazo.com/0dedfae143497bbc4062cf802e18d054

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the character you play as """

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """ Constructor function """

        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

        self.walking_frames_l = []
        self.walking_frames_r = []
        self.walking_frames_u = []
        self.walking_frames_d = []

        self.direction = "R"

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("character.png")
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(1, 6, 15, 22)
        self.walking_frames_d.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(17, 6, 15, 22)
        self.walking_frames_d.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(33, 6, 15, 22)
        self.walking_frames_d.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(49, 6, 15, 22)
        self.walking_frames_d.append(image)

        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 69, 15, 23)
        self.walking_frames_u.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(16, 69, 15, 23)
        self.walking_frames_u.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(32, 69, 15, 23)
        self.walking_frames_u.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48, 69, 15, 23)
        self.walking_frames_u.append(image)

        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(2, 38, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(18, 38, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(34, 38, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(50, 38, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)

        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(1, 102, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(17, 102, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(33, 102, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(49, 102, 13, 22)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(image)


        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[0]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

    def move(self, walls):
        """ Moves player """

        # Move left/right
        self.change_x = 0

        pos = self.rect.x
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.change_x = -8
            self.direction = "L"
        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.change_x = 8
            self.direction = "R"

        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        if self.direction == "R":
            frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_r)
            self.image = self.walking_frames_r[frame]

        else:
            frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_l)
            self.image = self.walking_frames_l[frame]


        # Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of
            # the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Move up/down
        self.change_y = 0

        pos = self.rect.y
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_w]:
            self.change_y = -8
            self.direction = "U"
        if keystate[pygame.K_s]:
            self.change_y = 8
            self.direction = "D"

        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        if self.direction == "D":
            frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_d)
            self.image = self.walking_frames_d[frame]

        else:
            frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_u)
            self.image = self.walking_frames_u[frame]

        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working, because if `self.direction` is not `"D"` then `self.image` is set by `self.walking_frames_u[frame]` in any case.
Note, the `else` case in the following statement is always executed, even if `self.direction` is `"L"` or `"R"`:

> ```py
> if self.direction == "D":
>    frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_d)
>    self.image = self.walking_frames_d[frame]
>
> else:
>    frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_u)
>    self.image = self.walking_frames_u[frame]
> ```

Combine the code which sets `self.image` in a single `if`-`elif`-`else` statement.
Furthermore you have to ensure that correct coordinate is used to compute the image index. Remove the variable `pos` and use `self.rect.x` respectively `self.rect.y` instead:

```py
if self.direction == "R":
    frame = (self.rect.x // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_r)
    self.image = self.walking_frames_r[frame]

elif self.direction == "L":
    frame = (self.rect.x // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_l)
    self.image = self.walking_frames_l[frame] 

elif self.direction == "D":
   frame = (self.rect.y // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_d)
   self.image = self.walking_frames_d[frame]

elif:
   frame = (self.rect.y // 30) % len(self.walking_frames_u)
   self.image = self.walking_frames_u[frame]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I combined them into the single statement, and that solved the problem of it not swapping to the left and right animations, but it still isn't playing the rest of the sprites in the list. Here's how it looks after I changed the code https://pastebin.com/Z3rxQ3F0, and here's a gif of how it looks in the game https://gyazo.com/f8f0dbef54cffd06c84e9ef64efcf3bd

Comment: @Tripzen I've changed the answer. `pos` is always set to `self.rect.y`. Remove `pos` and use `self.rect.x` respectively `self.rect.y`

Comment: Ah I see! pos was only set to player.rect.y since I combined it into one statement and moved it below both pos statements. Makes complete since. Thank you so much!